# I want use lower and upper case in the terminal for choosing

Tags: java

I want use lower and upper case in the terminal for choosing

in all cases in this code i can just use upper case, but I want use both

```
                case 'S ':
                {
                    System.out.println("File status: "+partyPlaner.getFileStatus());
                    break;
                }
                case 'N':
                {
                    System.out.print("Enter new name for planner:");
                    String newName = keyboard.nextLine();
                    partyPlaner.setPlannerName(newName);
                    break;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast the variable you are switching on to uppercase() for example.
So inside the switch statement, the variable will be in uppercase, and you only need to enter the uppercase "cases".

```
switch(s.toUpper()){...}
```

Comment: What should I do 
 public static void main(String args[])
    {
        char opt = ' ';
        PartyPlanner partyPlaner = new PartyPlanner();
        while(opt!='Q')
        {
            opt = menu();
            switch(opt)

Comment: public static void main(String args[])
    {
        char opt = ' ';
        PartyPlanner partyPlaner = new PartyPlanner();
        while(opt!='Q')
        {
            opt = menu();
            switch(opt)